# For some reason amdgpu stopped working

Tags: system

I'm desperate to get a resolution to this problem, the thing is a managed to get the drivers working on and r9 390, went to launch and when I go back the pc was shut off, I start it off and I got a black screen then I forced a shutdown and when I got it running the drivers stopped working for some reason, man I was so happy to get them working and now they stopped working, need to point I blacklisted radeon and im using amdgpu with `radeon.si_support=0` and `amgpu.si_suppport=1` also need to mention that `lspci -v` returns this in VGA part.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] (rev 80) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
I/O ports at e000 
Memory at efe00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

None of them works for some reason, I also blacklisted radeon.

Comment: Please update me on this, did you find something?